# Showing a Set is not Connected

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

The following comes from Conway's Complex Analysis book. Let $X = \{z : |z| \le 1 \} \cup \{z : |z-2|<1\} \subset \mathbb{C}$. I suspect that is is connected, but I am having difficulty demonstrating this. I could use some hints, tips, etc.

Here is the definition of connectedness that I am working with:

> A metric space $(X,d)$ is connected if the only subsets of $X$ that are both open and closed are $\emptyset$ and $X$. If $A \subseteq X$, then $A$ is connected if $(A,d)$ is connected.

Comment: The set is clearly path-connected. Do you know that implies connectedness?

Comment: No, this isn't mentioned before the concept of connectedness.

Comment: Do you know $\;A,\,B\;$ connected and $\;A\cap B\neq\emptyset\implies A\cup B\;$ connected? Otherwise, without path connectedness, it may become ugly and lengthy to prove...

Comment: @DonAntonio No, that is not mentioned either. However, what two sets $A$ and $B$ did you have in mind? I didn't realize $\{z : |z| \le 1 \}$ and $\{z : |z-2|<1\}$ overlapped.

Comment: @user193319 Well, then I think it is way easier to show something's **not** connected than connected...and right now I can't think of anything to help you with your current knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary that the set is the union of two disjoint open sets.  Take the open set (call $A$) that contains $z=1$.  Argue that any open set contain this point has to intersect both balls.  Now the other open set (call $B$) intersects one of the two balls non-trivally, call this ball $X$.  Now $X\cap A$ and $X\cap B$ are (relatively) open disjoint subsets of $X$ that are both non-empty and cover $X$, implying $X$, a ball, is non-connected.